# Troubles with Golang append() and for loop

Tags: go

I am trying to use a buffer to receive data from conn. I have a for loop around reader.Read and will break the loop when the reader comes back with an err stating EOF. However, it seems everything outside of the loop is no longer defined.

The second issue I am running into is I cannot append two slices. I try and use
`dataFile = append(dataFile, buff)` but it says that I cannot use []byte. To my understanding you are able to append two slices like that. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import (
  "fmt"
    "net"
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "os"
  "io"
)

func readData(conn net.Conn){
  fmt.Println("Reading data...\n")

  // Create a new reader from conn
  reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

  // Make a slice to hold all data being transmitted
  var dataFile []byte

  // Create a buffer to store information as it comes across conn
  buff := make([]byte, 4096)

  for {
  bytesReturned, err := reader.Read(buff)
  dataFile = append(dataFile, buff)
  if err != nil {
    if err != io.EOF{
      log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    break //Break the loop when err returns EOF
  }
}
  
  err = os.WriteFile("data.txt", dataFile, 0666)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
    

  fmt.Println("Read", bytesReturned,"bytes.")
}



// Start of main --------------------------------
func main(){

 //Listen on local port 80
 listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":5555")
 if err != nil {
   log.Fatalln("Unable to bind port")
 }

 fmt.Println("Port 5555 binded...\n")

 //handle multiple connections
 for {
   conn, err := listener.Accept()
   if err != nil {
     log.Fatalln("Unable to accept connection...")
   }
   go readData(conn)
 }
}
```

Here is a picture of the errors being received
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gJP9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the bytes read, not the buffer itself.

```
    bytesReturned, err := reader.Read(buff)
    dataFile = append(dataFile, buff[:bytesReturned]...)
```

Note the use of the [slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) to get a slice of the bytes read and the `...` to specify the contents of the slice as the arguments to `append`.

Use a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to declare `err` and assign the result of os.WriteFile to `err`.

```
err := os.WriteFile("data.txt", dataFile, 0666)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Use the length of the buffer to report the number of bytes read:

```
fmt.Println("Read", len(datafile),"bytes.")
```

Simplify the code by using io.ReadAll:

```
func readData(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Reading data...\n")
    dataFile, err := io.ReadAll(conn)
    if err != io.EOF {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    err = os.WriteFile("data.txt", dataFile, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Read", len(dataFile), "bytes.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line redefines `bytesReturned`, shadowing the definition in the outer scope:

```
  bytesReturned, err := reader.Read(buff)
```

Use:

```
var err error
bytesReturned, err = reader.Read(buff)
```

instead.

For appending, use `append(dataFile, buff...)`

Finally, `err` is not defined, because the only `err` used is in the for-loop, and since it is a different block, that `err` is not recognized outside. Use:

```
  err := os.WriteFile("data.txt", dataFile, 0666)
```

Instead.

Most of the program can be replaced with a call to `io.Copy`.

Comment: Note that `io.Copy` will generally be much more efficient, too.